# How to auto selected save value from database in to select HTML tag

Tags: php, html, mysqli

How to auto select the save value fetched from database in to select HTML tag.

I have a list of rooms with Hotel name , room type , facilities , descriptions  in a table. i want to edit that record . when i click on edit button it fetch room_id to edit row accordingly, all other values successfully auto fetched in textboxes except values in select tag.

Here is my code to fetch values from database and echo to corresponding textboxes , except select box . i would like to auto select value in select box.

```
$query = "SELECT * from room where room_id = '$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  { 
       $room_id=$row['room_id'];
        $room_type_id=$row['room_type_id'];
        $facilities = $row['facilities'];
        $long_description=$row['long_description'];
}
         ?>

                  <form action="Edit_Room_Script.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">


                <label class="form-label">Hotel Name</label> 
<select class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
<?php
$sel_cus = "select hotel_name from hotels ";
$res_cus = mysqli_query($connection, $sel_cus);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_cus)) {?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['hotel_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['hotel_name'];?></option><?php}?>
</select>

<label class="form-label">Room Type</label> 
<select class="form-control" name="room_type" id="room_type">
<?php
$sel_cus = "select Room_Type_Id,Room_Type_Name from room_type ";
$res_cus = mysqli_query($connection, $sel_cus);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_cus)) {?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['Room_Type_Id'];?>">
<?php echo $row['Room_Type_Name'];?></option>
<?php
} 
?>
</select>
<label class="form-label">Facilities</label> 
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="facilities" value="<?php echo $facilities;?>" name="facilities" autocomplete="Off"  required >

<button class="btn btn-success btn-cons" type="submit" name="update" id="update"> Update Room</button>
</form>
```

i have a row in my html table is like below

Sr       Hotel Name                 Roomtype      Facility  Action

1        Serena                     Super         ABC           Edit

When i click to edit button it take me to edit from where facility value successfully auto fetched from database and set in text box but hotel name and room type is not set. In select tag for hotel name and room type it populates all the hotel name and room type except serena and super how could i achieve this  Please guide with some code.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some modifications:

1) Get `$hotel_id`

2) To show `<select>` element selected, you need to add `selected="selected"` attribute in your `<option>` tag.

If you have a drop down HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="room_type" id="room_type">
<option value="1">Villa</option>
<option value="2">Terrace</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected">Gallery</option>
<option value="4">Delux</option>
</select>
```

Drop down will show `Gallery` selected.

In your case, you can show it by:

```
<?php
$sel_cus = "select Room_Type_Id,Room_Type_Name from room_type ";
$res_cus = mysqli_query($connection, $sel_cus);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_cus)) {?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['Room_Type_Id'];?>"
<?php if ($room_type_id == $row['Room_Type_Id']) { echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>
<?php echo $row['Room_Type_Name'];?></option>
<?php
} 
?>
```

3) Also, first fetch the arrays from database and then loop over them in the `<select>` element as writing fetching code directly in `<select>` is a bad practise and in case of any issue, it my expose your database field names.

Comment: i achieve what i want . successfully auto selected value from database in to select tag.

can you please tell me what is the good practice ?

Thank you so much

Comment: Good Practise is to fetch all database info in arrays in the top of file. And loop over arrays for displaying drop down arrays. Also, avoid multiple database query interactions.

Comment: Sir actually i am not much familiar wit h PHP , would you please guide me through example.

Comment: Actually, you need to practise a lot, search on internet for PHP tips and tricks. Its not a one day process. Best of luck :)

Comment: this is what i think you are avoiding me :)
anyway thank you

Comment: @MuhammadTanzeelArshad, I am not avoiding you, first thing. Read my answer carefully, read my comments. You can find a lot of guidance there. If you still think I need to guide more, please follow my blog code2real.blogspot.com

Comment: Post comments there and I will create posts for you. If you respond to the blog, you will learn from new posts. I can add posts for you there.

Comment: You are most welcome to learn PHP. Add comments to the blog and ask me to guide on a topic and a totally new detailed post will be added to the blog. Along with you, many will be benefited. Is it OK?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191143/discussion-between-pupil-and-muhammad-tanzeel-arshad).

Comment: sir i appreciate you and really want to thank you i will do the same IA.

Comment: Meanwhile, you can read my other answers to look into how to solve problems.